# Link error on glGenVertexArrays et glBindVertexArray

Tags: c++, opengl, hyperlink

I'm learning OpenGL and i have issue with just a simple triangle...

I get a link error with glGenVertexArrays et glBindVertexArray.

When i delete these 2 lines, my program has no link error.

I linked with freeglut, glew64, glew32, glew32s just in case. My program is configured as x64.

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID); // ERROR HERE
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID); // ERROR HERE

static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint vertexbuffer;

glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    0,                  correspondre au « layout » dans le shader 
    3,                 
    GL_FLOAT,            
    GL_FALSE,    
    0,
    (void*)0 
    );

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Démarre à partir du sommet 0; 3 sommets au total -> 1 triangle 

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Link errors :

```
error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___glewGenVertexArrays
error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp___glewBindVertexArrays
```

I'm programming on VS 2013, my GC is a GTX 970 and my drivers are up to date.

I tried on a sample of CUDA and is does the same thing.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I have this exact issue.  Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i set the preprocessor flash : GLEW_STATIC and now the others functions are shown as external symbol unresolved.

In my depedencies i have : glew32s.lib and glew64.lib.   Am I right ?

I already included `#include <GL/glew.h>`